# sonata sandbox blocking the Symfony2 exceptions?

Tags: symfony, sandbox, sonata

I'm trying to understand how works sonata sandbox...

I have created a new route and trigged:

```
php app/console sonata:page:update-core-routes --site=3
```

the landingpage was creaded successfuly,

then  :

```
php app/console sonata:page:create-snapshots --site=3
```

theoretically  all is well created,

but my route is pointing to a own controller with my own template and my own block return any response...

sure that i have done something wrong in my block or in my template, but I'm really surprised because when I do a probe to see until where the script run well... for exaple:

```
 //in my action
 $this->asdfasdfasdfasfd();
```

I'm no getting any response,  only a white screen.  somebody know why? and how can I solve?

Comment: Did you check the raw Apache or httpd error logs? Things like parsing errors and bad PHP markup will cause the autoloader to fail before the kernel can even catch the PHP errors and send them to `prod.log` or `dev.log`. Instead, you have to check `error_logs` for your vhost or `php_error_logs`.. it varies between LAMP configurations

Comment: thanks! I have found the error in error_logs... I have another symfony2 project running with the same apache configuration but without the sonata sandbox and I'm getting not this problem... so.. what is exactly that I should consider in my apache configuration??  thanks!!!

Comment: Could you post the error? It would help me tell you what the problem is.

Comment: yes but what do you mean exactly? the app_dev.log?? the errors.log i thing is irrelevant because only is inserted the issue i have produced on purpose.

Comment: I see. I could only understand the latter problem with your blank page. "but my route is pointing to a own controller with my own template and my own block return any response..." doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: sorry!! english is not my lenguage :/

Comment: app.DEBUG: Router Sonata\PageBundle\Route\CmsPageRouter was not able to match, message "/index"

Comment: that I wanted to say wiht the own controller, template and block is that  my route point to my controller: in  MyBundle:Controller:myAction

Comment: And this action return a Template "myBundle::MyTemplate.html.twig